# eslint no-restricted-imports - prevent an import from from path ending with pattern

Tags: eslint, glob, gitignore

According to the [eslint no-restricted-imports documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports)

> When using the object form, you can also specify an array of
> ***gitignore-style patterns***:
>
> ```
> "no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
>     "paths": ["import1", "import2"],
>     "patterns": ["import1/private/*", "import2/*", "!import2/good"] }]
> ```

(Emphasis mine)

What I'm trying to do is restrict imports from parent index files - as this is causing issues with cyclical dependencies (I am also using the `import/no-cycle` rule, but it makes sense to also explicitly use this rule.)

That is, I want to ban imports like:

```
import foo from "../.."; 
import bar from "../../..";
```

I also want to ban imports like:

```
import a from "../Components";
```

but not like

```
import  b from "../Components/Foo";
```

I have tried using this rule:

```
'no-restricted-imports': [
  'error', 
  {
    patterns: [
      '**/..', 
      '**/Components'
    ]
  },
```

But this causes on errors on imports of:

```
import  b from "../Components/Foo";
```

Is there a way to specify 'end of string' in a gitignore style pattern?

Comment: Possible dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556068/eslint-how-can-i-restrict-certain-paths-with-no-restricted-imports-but-allow but it didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 10):

First, make sure you don't have set [`import/no-relative-parent-imports`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-relative-parent-imports.md), or any `../` import would fail.

Second, if this really follows `.gitignore` rules, you cannot have rules for folders (like `**/..` or `**/Components`).
Because, once you ignore a *folder*, any other rule for elements *inside* that folder would be ignored.

Try:

```
'no-restricted-imports': [
  'error', 
  {
    patterns: [
      '**/../*', 
      '!**/../Components', 
      '**/../Components/*', 
      '!**/../Components/Foo', 
    ]
  },
```

Comment: It's not really going to work to manually put in exceptions for each sub forlder

Comment: @dwjohnston I meant, try it as a test, in order to establish it does behaves as a .gitignore. If it does, I will edit my answer.